# How to calculate mean spatial location by group

Tags: r, dplyr, geospatial

I need to calculate mean locations for a spatial data with longitude and latitude variables. The operation needs to be done by group, which somewhat complicates the matters. I have been able to do this for a simple weighted mean (example below), but a more sophisticated measure is not as easy to implement.

Example data:

```r
df <- data.frame(longitude = c(22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27),
                 latitude = c(56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61),
                 weight = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                 group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"))
```

Simple weighted mean:

```r
dfMean <- df %>%
      group_by(group) %>%
      summarize_at(vars(longitude, latitude), list(~weighted.mean(., weight))) %>%
      ungroup
```

I want to calculate this with a function `geopshere::geomean`. The problem is that the function's output is a two-column matrix, which is not compatible with `dplyr::summarize`. Any suggestions on how to achieve this efficiently?

Comment: wrap it with `as.tbl` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to get the value from `geomean` into a comma-separated string and then `separate` them into different columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(geosphere)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(val = toString(geomean(cbind(longitude, latitude), weight))) %>%
  separate(val, c("cord1", "cord2"), sep = ",") %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, as.numeric)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#    group cord1 cord2
#    <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   A      23.3  57.3
#2   B      26.3  60.3
```

Comment: This was the fastest solutions by `microbenchmark`. The others are otherwise valid solutions too.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to nest the data by group and then use `map()` to iterate over the grouped data.

```
library(geosphere)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  nest(-group) %>%
  mutate(gmean = map(data, ~data.frame(geomean(xy = cbind(.x$longitude, .x$latitude), w = .x$weight)))) %>%
  unnest(gmean)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  group data                 x     y
  <fct> <list>           <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     <tibble [3 x 3]>  23.3  57.3
2 B     <tibble [3 x 3]>  26.3  60.3
```

Or the same thing using `summarise`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(gmean = list(data.frame(geomean(cbind(longitude, latitude), w = weight)))) %>%
  unnest(gmean)
```